# scribe oauth connection refused

Tags: facebook-graph-api, openid, scribe

I am trying to use scribe. Just copied the Facebook example it asked to paste the code, which I got in request after login to FB. as below

> And paste the authorization code here
>
> > > AQB7XIMSqkD_OjE_bbHAz4nWQxkuWrQLUmCsYcw5VW4Tlxti3PEA-8F7YGNLKhonX0tBzA2GaXpt7Mz7ym83j4aeXc6kCHurqSRVbB8DpXSjnnkh3cm3XwUHJEfuOeo3Zf_gEFOtlJDvET-b38ECz4Y4jke5gCSmu9NIndG376M4r4siNXGopHq8VO4fQSw9tg_1O27GR3CNSbKVrx1Mk-GqPIhVHg28Zt5zikthZ7l9t8zI_nXIo6T3F17FJxQGMT8NZL8kGh4fUmGAMKCHouP964b_67F6ddQ3K6u1C4KNdSfNiLY76Qude8OWtweeK1Tou29hvs1iJojuMaWEs8Va

I am getting this error.

```
Trading the Request Token for an Access Token...
Exception in thread "main" org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthConnectionException: There was a problem while creating a connection to the remote service.
    at org.scribe.model.Request.send(Request.java:70)
    at org.scribe.model.Request.send(Request.java:76)
    at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth20ServiceImpl.getAccessToken(OAuth20ServiceImpl.java:36)
    at com.ibm.fb.FacebookExample.main(FacebookExample.java:36)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:80)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:369)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:176)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:402)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:590)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.connect(qc.java:559)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.pc.connect(pc.java:47)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:192)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:407)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:502)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.<init>(c.java:60)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.a(c.java:62)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.getNewHttpClient(d.java:6)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:940)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:63)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.connect(b.java:76)
    at org.scribe.model.Response.<init>(Response.java:29)
    at org.scribe.model.Request.doSend(Request.java:117)
    at org.scribe.model.Request.send(Request.java:66)
    ... 3 more
```

Someone please point out where its going wrong.

Regards.

Adeeb

Comment: No one can tell you where you went wrong because you didn't supply any source code. If you want your question answered, please provide the code you are using. In general, connection refused is not anything to do with the source code, but more to do with the URL you're trying to hit. Make sure the URL you're hitting is valid.

Comment: Change http to https in the URL you are using in OAuthRequest, it worked for me.